# What exactly is the KKT check and what is the point of it?

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization, high-dimensional, constrained-optimization

In the paper for strong screening rules for the lasso ([link](https://tibshirani.su.domains/ftp/strong.pdf)), the following screening algorithm is proposed (start of chapter 7):

Let $S(\lambda)$ be the strong rule set. Then the following strategy is adopted:

1. Set $\mathcal{E} = S(\lambda)$.
2. Solve the problem at value $\lambda$ using only the predictors in $\mathcal{E}$.
3. Check the KKT conditions at this solution for all predictors. If there are no violations, we are
   done. Otherwise, add the predictors that violate the KKT conditions to the set $\mathcal{E}$, and repeat
   steps (2) and (3).

I have a few questions about this:

- What exactly is the KKT check? I can see the KKT condition is given by
  $$
  \mathbf{x}_j^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X} \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}})=\lambda \gamma_j \quad \text { for } j=1, \ldots p
  $$
  where $\gamma_j$ is the $j$ th component of the subgradient of $\|\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\|_1$ :
  $$
  \gamma_j \in \begin{cases}\{+1\} & \text { if } \hat{\beta}_j>0 \\ \{-1\} & \text { if } \hat{\beta}_j<0 \\ {[-1,1]} & \text { if } \hat{\beta}_j=0\end{cases}
  $$
  Does this mean that for each predictor I need to check whether this is met? For example, if I have a variable such that $\hat{\beta}_i = 0$ from step (2), do I need to check that the KKT is satisfied with the last subgradient case? How can I check this for all predictors when I only have $\hat{\beta}$ values for those in $\mathcal{E}$?
- For step (3), what happens if the KKT violation occurs only for a single variable in $\mathcal{E}$? Surely then I am repeating the steps but $\mathcal{E}$ has stayed the same, so we would not expect a different output? Following this reasoning, why do we even need to check the KKT condition for variables in $\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: The KKT conditions are a fundamental technique of *constrained optimization.*  A good place to learn about them would be an optimization textbook or a comprehensive numerical analysis textbook.  They are a more precise statement of the Lagrange multiplier conditions for multiple inequalities and equalities.

Comment: This comment is regarding your second bullet. These screening rules are not about changing the output of the optimization; rather, they are about identifying coefficients which are *definitely* going to be $0$, and thus whose updates can be skipped, speeding up the overall procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KKT condition is automatically satisfied for predictors in the active set as a result of step 2, so you only need to check it for predictors that aren't in the active set.

Comment: Why does the algorithm state to check it for all predictors in step 3?

Comment: That's not really a statistics question